# PHP MySQL Cannot use "INSERT INTO"

Tags: php, mysql, insert, user-registration, undefined-index

I have created a webpage named Register.php which should insert data into my database. The problem with this is that the registration page works but then when I try to log in the information was not added into my database is there anything that I did wrong that I cannot find?

```
<?php
    echo "<h1>Register</h1>";
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    //form data
    $FullName = strip_tags($_POST['FullName']);
    $UserName = strip_tags($_POST['UserName']);
    $Password = strip_tags($_POST['Password']);
    $RepeatPassword = strip_tags($_POST['RepeatPassword']);
    if ($submit)
    {   
        //open database
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("cs266db_db1");

        $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT UserName FROM user_ID WHERE UserName='$UserName'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
        if ($count!=0)
        {
            die("UserName already taken");
        }       
        //check for existence
        if($FullName&&$UserName&&$Password&&$RepeatPassword)
        {        
            //check password and repeat password match
            if($Password==$RepeatPassword)
            {         
                //check length of username and fullname
                if (strlen($UserName) > 25 || strlen($FullName)>25)
                {
                    echo "Length of username or fullname is over 25 characters!";
                }
                else {
                   //check password
                   if(strlen($Password)>25 || strlen($Password) < 6) {
                     echo "Password must be between 6 and 25 characters";
                   } else {              
                        //encrypt password
                        $Password = md5($Password);
                        $RepeatPassword = md5($RepeatPassword);                              
                        $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_id VALUES (FullName='".$FullName."',UserName='".$UserName."',Password='".$Password."'");             
                    }
                   die("You have been registered <a href='index1.php'> Return to Login Page </a>");          
                }           
            }
            else{
                echo "Your passwords do not match";
            }        
        } else {
           echo "Please fill in all fields!";    
        }  
    }
?>

<html>    
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Your full name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="FullName" value="<?php echo $FullName ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Choose a username:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $UserName ?>"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Choose a password:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="Password">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Repeat your password:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="RepeatPassword">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>        
  <br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">                
</form>    
</html>
```

Im getting an error of this as well(I am running on netbeans):

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in
>   C:\Xampp\htdocs\Resume_DB\register.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined
>   index: FullName in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Resume_DB\register.php on line 7
>   Notice: Undefined index: UserName in
>   C:\Xampp\htdocs\Resume_DB\register.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined
>   index: Password in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Resume_DB\register.php on line 9
>   Notice: Undefined index: RepeatPassword in
>   C:\Xampp\htdocs\Resume_DB\register.php on line 10

Does this have to do with my problem of insertion? If so can you help! Please and thank you!

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Comment: Your insert syntax is incorrect.

Comment: It's sort of good that this isn't working because if it was working it would do the exact opposite of what you intend: Instead of locking people out of your system with a password it lets anyone take over your system completely and get whatever they want out of your database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the the way you run the insert is even valid in MySql,
I just tried it on my MySql on wamp and the line does not return error but all the values that are been insert are NULL
I'm talking about this line

```
insert into tmp_table values (`field_1`='value_1', `field_2`='value_2', `field_3`='value_3' ...)
```

Do you get empty rows in your DB or no rows at all ?